# how to delete a specific data of an entity in google app engine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I can delete an entity using the [Deleting The entity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Deleting_an_Entity) given by Google Document, But my question is how to delete a specific data that is stored inside an entity. Do we have any way to delete a specific data inside the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about getting the entity, removing the desired field(s) and then updating it?

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Updating_an_Entity) :

*"To update an existing entity, modify the attributes of the Entity object, then pass it to the DatastoreService.put() method"*

Comment: I think its only for deleting the entity not the data inside the entity. Is there any way to use delete.(mydata) methods to handle it?